# Enforcing user authentication on entire include of URL

Tags: django, django-authentication

So I have this pip app that I installed on my Django environment, and made it available on my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'newapp/', include('newapp.urls')),

]
```

Turns out this app has some sections that one can access without being logged in. How could I enforce a `login required` decorator on the entire include url?

Comment: `urlpatterns = patterns(' ', (r'^$', login_required(views.your_index), 'name'),` - This can be a solution, But you should write login_required in your views.

Comment: The views aren't mine, thats a delivered app that I installed